# how to fix Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component ERROR

Tags: reactjs, algolia

I have this `component` in React that is using Algolia searchClient.

```
const Hit = ({hit}) => {
    const [socialNetworkHtml, setSocialNetworkHtml] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        let socialNetwork = hit['Social Network'];
        let socialNetworkHtml = socialNetwork.map((network, index) => {
            return (
                <span key={index}>
                    <img className='small-logo' src={require(`../../assets/socialNetworks/${network}.png`)}/>
                </span>
            );
        });
        setSocialNetworkHtml(socialNetworkHtml);
        return () => {
            setSocialNetworkHtml([]);
        };
    }, [hit]);

    return (
        <div className="hit-card">
            <a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href={`${hit.Website}`}>
                <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${hit.Image})` }} className="card-image"></div>
                <h4 className="hit-name">
                    <Highlight attribute="Name" hit={hit} />
                </h4>
                <b>Used for :</b>
                {socialNetworkHtml}
                <b>Works on:</b><br/>
                <p className='hit-card--details'> {hit.Deployment}</p>
            </a>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I am getting these error:

> "uncaught TypeError: socialNetwork.map is not a function
> at FindWhatYouNeed.js:34:1"
>
> "Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted
> component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your
> application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks
> in a useEffect cleanup function."

When I try to switch the pages. Do you have any idea how i can fix it?

I am trying to convert a value from the `object` that is on the Algolia server, to an img.

Comment: what is this `hit` prop? Are you sure that it is an array?

Comment: 1. There's no need for "return () => {
        setSocialNetworkHtml([]);
    };" as this will run after the component is unmounted, hence the error.
2. I'd suggest to get rid of "socialNetworkHtml" and moving the "socialNetwork .map" into the jsx.

Comment: I tried going in this direction, but it still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I see three potential problems here:

your return callback in the useEffect.

```
return () => {
  setSocialNetworkHtml([]);
};
```

it's trying to perform a state update, "setSocialNetworkHtml", when the component is unmounted. You can just remove it and not replace it with anything

Also, you shouldn't be creating the html in the useEffect, more something like:

```
const Hit = ({ hit }) => {
  const [socialNetwork, setSocialNetwork] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    setSocialNetworkHtml(hit['Social Network'])
  }, [hit])

  return (
    <div className="hit-card">
      <a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href={`${hit.Website}`}>
        <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${hit.Image})` }} className="card-image"></div>
        <h4 className="hit-name">
          <Highlight attribute="Name" hit={hit} />
        </h4>
        <b>Used for :</b>
        {socialNetwork.map((network, index) => (
          <span key={index}>
            <img
              className="small-logo"
              src={require(`../../assets/socialNetworks/${network}.png`)}
            />
          </span>
        ))}
        <b>Works on:</b>
        <br />
        <p className="hit-card--details"> {hit.Deployment}</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  )
}
```

- Thirdly, i'm not sure you should be using inline requires for the image sources, but i'm also not sure you shouldn't

Comment: This fixes the ```TypeError: socialNetwork.map``` error indeed, but not the second one.

Comment: Thanks, but no luck, same error :(